# Waiting for all actions to be executed after clicking a button in selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i'm sorry if it's been answered before but i really couldn't find a good solution to my problem

I have an email input field and i want to check that when you input an invalid email an error message appears.
my code looks somthing like this:

```
private void LoadElements()
{
     Email = driver.FindElement(By.Id("MainContent_Email"));
     SaveButton = driver.FindElement(By.Id("MainContent_SaveButton"));
     ErrorMessage = driver.FindElement(By.Id("MainContent_PersDetsError"));
}
public void test()
{
     //Email, SaveButton & Error are IWebElement
     LoadElements();
     Email.Clear();
     Email.SendKeys(emailString);
     SaveButton.Click();
     // Avoid stale element exception on refresh after a successful save:
     LoadElements();
     Assert.IsTrue(ErrorMessage.Displayed);
}
```

My problem is that when i try to purposly fail the test (input a valid email), some of the time I still get a stale element exception. I presume this happens becuse LoadElements() loads the web elements too quickly.

My question is this: is there a way to wait for the page to fully load before executing any commends?

PS I tried the following code and it didn't work for me

```
IWait<IWebDriver> wait = new OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30.00));

 wait.Until(driver1 => ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("return document.readyState").Equals("complete"));
```

Comment: We will need to see what `LoadElements` actually does and what specific line it fails on.

Comment: use a thread.sleep() wait